# does the Pi Camera require Desktop?

Tags: camera, pi-zero

I have a Pi **Zero** WH, **headless** running **Raspian-buster-lite**.  Can I attach a Pi Camera and have it capture an image to the SD when triggered by a motion sensor or proximity sensor?  Or will I have to use an OS with a graphical user interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a GUI desktop  ... you can have your C or Python program run and interact with the Camera to capture images and save them as JPGs without any GUI desktop at all...